# Verifyauthentication method of Facebookclient(oAuth) doesn't give any data

Tags: dotnetopenauth, facebook-oauth

I am using Facebook client to access my MVC4 application through DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet. But after successfull login i am not able to fetch any data Such as ProviderName, UserName and UserId from VerifyAuthentication. i am able to get the data for Linkedin, Google, Yahoo and Microsoft but not for facebook. Below is my code for the same.

```
OAuth2ConfigurationSection section = _proxy.GetOAuthConfigurationFacebook();
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(section.AppID, section.AppSecret);
Uri uri = new Uri(section.ReturnUrl);
var auth =client.VerifyAuthentication(filterContext.HttpContext,uri);
```

GetOAuthConfigurationFacebook Method fetches AppId and SecretId from config file.
I am getting null in

```
var auth =client.VerifyAuthentication(filterContext.HttpContext,uri);
```

i am not sure what i am missing?